# Provider changes in angular 2 final version

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-providers

In angular 2.0.0-rc.1 we have created Provider using new Provider, refer below code snippet

var constAccessor = **new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { 
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => EJDefaultValueAccessor), multi: true 
        });**

```
    var valDirective = Directive({selector: selector, 
        host: { '(change)': 'onChange($event.value)', '(focusOut)': 'onTouched()' }, 
        providers: [constAccessor]
    })
```

Which is used to create a directive, but when porting to angular final release i am not able to find a solution. Checked change log in below location

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map literal like:

```
var constAccessor = { 
   provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
   useExisting: forwardRef(() => EJDefaultValueAccessor), 
   multi: true 
};
```

See also

- [ANGULAR 2 PROVIDERS USING MAP LITERALS](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/13/angular-2-providers-using-map-literals.html)